# openssh sftp on windows log sftp to file

Tags: windows, ssh, sftp

I have activated the openssh server on a windows server 2019. SFTP works fine, but I can't get it to log to a file, I activated file logging in sshd_config with this:

```
# Logging
SyslogFacility LOCAL0
LogLevel INFO
```

and also for the sftp subsystem:
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe -l INFO

I do get something logged to the file

```
3876 2020-09-23 14:26:50.392 Server listening on :: port 22.
3876 2020-09-23 14:26:50.393 Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
6528 2020-09-23 14:28:04.841 Accepted password for xxxxxxxxx from xxxxxxxxxx port 62200 ssh2
12152 2020-09-23 14:31:23.815 Accepted password for xxxxxxxxxxxx from xxxxxxxxxxx port 58256 ssh2
9392 2020-09-23 14:31:24.195 Received disconnect from xxxxxxxxxxx port 58256:11: disconnected by user
9392 2020-09-23 14:31:24.195 Disconnected from xxxxxxxx port 58256
```

but everything else (what files are transferred etc) goes to the Windows eventlog which is inconvinient. Is there a way to completely log to a file? Also it would be great if that file location could be changed (currently it's under the ssh directory in %ProgramData%